# Accelerometer error report

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am quite new to Android programming.

I tried to write several codes, but I got stuck in an accelerometer program. After loading the program to the emulator, it responds *"`Adil_acceleration_3rd` had stopped"*.

I provide you my files:

**Xml file:**

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/acceleration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="X: Y: Z:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my `ActivityMain.java` file:

```
package com.example.adil_acceleration_3rd;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

    Sensor accelerometer;
    SensorManager sm;
    TextView acceleration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        acceleration.setText("X:"+event.values[0]+
                "\nY:"+event.values[1]+
                "\nZ:"+event.values[2]);
    }

}
```

LogCat messages:

```
03-16 13:26:41.210: E/Trace(1926): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-16 13:26:41.210: W/Trace(1926): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-16 13:26:41.210: W/Trace(1926): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-16 13:26:41.210: W/Trace(1926): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-16 13:26:41.280: W/Trace(1926): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-16 13:26:41.280: W/Trace(1926): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-16 13:26:41.871: W/Trace(1926): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-16 13:26:41.871: D/AndroidRuntime(1926): Shutting down VM
03-16 13:26:41.871: W/dalvikvm(1926): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4d31908)
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at com.example.adil_acceleration_3rd.MainActivity.onSensorChanged(MainActivity.java:46)
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SystemSensorManager.java:204)
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 13:27:04.801: I/Process(1926): Sending signal. PID: 1926 SIG: 9
```

Comment: In the emulator sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER); probably return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the logcat carefully in these cases. Most of the time it will give a good hint or at a minimum the location of the problem.

In your case, the important lines are here:

```
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926): java.lang.NullPointerException 
03-16 13:26:41.880: E/AndroidRuntime(1926): at com.example.adil_acceleration_3rd.MainActivity.onSensorChanged(MainActivity.java:46)
```

This is this line:

```
acceleration.setText("X:"+event.values[0]+
```

It's happening because `acceleration` was declared, but never initialized.

P.S. For your next question, please format the logcat output for easier reading.

Comment: Thank you so much,I was successfully able to emulate the program,..
P.S. It was my first question,however I will try to pay attention for my next questions

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that worked for you (will motivate people to help you in the future and help future readers of your question) and wish you success in your next projects.